# How to change property in column array with jsstore

Tags: javascript, sql, angular, typescript

I have this jsstore table

```
    const tblInvoice: ITable = {
      name: "invoice",
      columns: {
        // Here "Id" is name of column
        id: { autoIncrement: true, primaryKey: true, notNull: false },
        branchId: { notNull: true, dataType: DATA_TYPE.Number },
        invoiceNumber: { notNull: false, dataType: DATA_TYPE.String },
        totalDiscount: { notNull: true, dataType: DATA_TYPE.Number },
        amountPaid: { notNull: true, dataType: DATA_TYPE.Number },
        remainingAmount: { notNull: true, dataType: DATA_TYPE.Number },
        createAt: { notNull: true, dataType: DATA_TYPE.DateTime },
        client: { notNull: false, dataType: DATA_TYPE.Object },
        total: { notNull: true, dataType: DATA_TYPE.Number },
        netTotal: { notNull: true, dataType: DATA_TYPE.Number },
        productsCount: { notNull: true, dataType: DATA_TYPE.Number },
        items: { notNull: true, dataType: DATA_TYPE.Array, multiEntry: true },
      },
      version: this.currentVersion,
    };
```

and I need to change property value in column items like quantity

Answer (score 0):

You just have to create a second version :

```
var table1 = {
    name: "table_name",
     columns: {
        column1: { dataType: 'datatype', primaryKey: true },
        column2 : { dataType: 'datatype'},
        ..... ,
        columnN: { dataType: 'datatype' }
    },
    version: 2 //Default version is 1.
}
```

https://jsstore.net/tutorial/change-table-design/

And dont set your jsstore with `const`

Comment: I need to change property value not table design

Comment: Your table design declare you property value, you cant change only 1 property of 1 value, it's not how it works